# Remove or revert previous commit in master from local

Tags: git, github

Accidentally I committed my change on master instead of new branch i want revert back this commit.

---

Is it possible to remove this commit?

Answer (score 2):

If you already pushed your commit use [git revert](https://de.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/undoing-changes/git-revert), otherwise you can use [git reset](https://de.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/undoing-changes/git-reset).

If you want to delve deeper, this thread is for you: [How to undo last commit(s) in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-do-you-undo-the-last-commit)